# combineLatest on CurrentValueSubject doesn't emit when combining with @Published property

Tags: ios, swift, swift5, combine

I am using Combine with Swift5; I have a `CurrentValueSubject` that I am combining with a `@Published` dictionary variable.

The problem is that when the current value is updated, map never gets called! This is specifically an issue with `@Published` variable since it works with other streams that are not using `@Published`.

```
@Published var userModels: [String: UserModel] = [:]
var chatModels: CurrentValueSubject<[ChatModelFirebase], Never> = CurrentValueSubject([])

chatModels
    .combineLatest(userModels.publisher)
    .map({ (chatModels, userModels) -> [ChatViewModel] in
        print("Hello") // Never gets called! 
        return []
        })
.assign(to: \.chatViewModels, on: self)
.store(in: &cancellableSet)


// Update chat model's value, and notice that map never gets called!
chatModels.values = []
```

There are no errors, code compiles and runs, but I never get the results of stream updates. **The problem will be fixed if I update `userModels` to also be `CurrentValueSubject`, but the question is why is `combineLatest(..)` breaking with `@Published`?**

Comment: It's never called because `userModels` is empty, so `userModels.publisher` sends 0 values, and `combineLatest` never sends a tuple (it's waiting for at least the first value)

Comment: @NewDev the `combineLatest` documentation states that it will get called when either of the publishers emit, `Subscribes to an additional publisher and publishes a tuple upon receiving output from either publisher.` See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/currentvaluesubject. So even if `userModels` is empty, any updates to `chatModels` should get reflected.

Comment: yes, but it waits for at least the first value from each (otherwise, it can't form a tuple). After that it publishes with a new value in either, combining with the latest from the other

Comment: Also, bear in mind that you're not actually using the `Published` publisher - you're using the `Sequence` publisher of the dictionary. If `userModels` changes, this wouldn't send new values into your pipeline. If you want to use the `Published` publisher - you should use: `$userModels`

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confusing between two publishers: the `Published<Value>.Publisher` publisher created from a `@Published` property via `$userModels` and the `Publishers.Sequence` publisher that you get from `userModels.publisher`.

---

The `Published` one publishes the value on every change. So, `$userModels` would publish the the `[:]` value right away, and then again with every change:

```
class Foo {
  @Published var dict: [String: Int] = [:]
}
let foo = Foo()

foo.$dict
   .sink { print($0) }

foo.dict = ["one": 1, "two": 2]
```

the output is:

```
[:]
["one": 1, "two": 2]
```

---

The `Sequence` publisher publishes each value from a sequence, which for a dictionary is a series of tuples of `(key, value)`. For an empty sequence, it publishes **no values**:

```
var dict: [String: Int] = [:]

dict.publisher
  .sink { print($0) } // will not print anything
```

---

In your case, you're using `.combineLatest` with a `Sequence` publisher from an empty dictionary, which publishes no values, and so `CombineLatest` publishes no values.

What you might have be looking for was to subscribe to a `Published` publisher of `userModels` property:

```
chatModels.combineLatest($userModels)
   .sink { print($0) }
```

the initial output then would immediately be:

```
([:], [])
```